# Return type in scala generic

Tags: scala, generics

I am pretty new to scala, and i have hard time with generic in some case.
I try to find simple example to illustrate my issue

let's start by setting 3 simple maps

```
scala> val map1 = Map[String, String]("A" -> "toto", "B" -> "tutu")
map1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(A -> toto, B -> tutu)

scala> val map2 = Map[String, Int]("B" -> 2)
map2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(B -> 2)

scala> val map3 = Map[String, String]("A" -> "foo")
map3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(A -> foo)
```

if i merge using ++

```
scala> map1 ++ map2
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any] = Map(A -> toto, B -> 2)
```

My map became [String, Any] which is what i want to reproduce

I create new method in Map class

```
object MapUtils {
    implicit class utils[K, V](map: Map[K, V]) {
        def myUselessMethod(merge: Map[K, V]): Map[K, V] = {
            map ++ merge
        }
    }
}
import MapUtils._

scala> map1 myUselessMethod map3
res4: Map[String,String] = Map(A -> foo, B -> tutu)

scala> map1 myUselessMethod map2
<console>:18: error: type mismatch;
found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]
required: Map[String,String]
        map1 myUselessMethod map2
```

How should i define my method so that it can return [String, Any]

I also checked scala MAP API to see if i can have some indications
https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/Map.html
but

```
++[B >: (K, V), That](that: GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: 
CanBuildFrom[Map[K, V], B, That]): That
```

is somehow indecipherable for me...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give the compiler some slack in the return type:

```
object MapUtils {
    implicit class utils[K, V](map: Map[K, V]) {
        def myUselessMethod[L >: V](merge: Map[K, L]): Map[K, L] = {
            map ++ merge
        }
    }
}
import MapUtils._

val map1 = Map[String, String]("A" -> "toto", "B" -> "tutu")
val map2 = Map[String, Int]("B" -> 2)

map1 myUselessMethod map2
```

Now it will infer the least upper bound `L` of `V` and the value type of the `merge`-argument map. In case of `Int` and `String`, `L` would be inferred to be `Any`.